# Will turning PostgreSQL database into PostGIS spatialy aware project and using it to store all web data?

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis

I'm starting my first website, and first big project and GIS is at the core. However I'm curious as to how will PostGIS change the PostgreSQL database. Will it make the database sub-optimal for storing everyday website stuff? Such as user information, messages, comments, callenders...ex. And are their any advantages for doing so considering I'm most likely going to be sending GeoJson requests to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will [installing PostGIS] make the database sub-optimal for storing everyday website stuff?

No, not at all. It just adds a bunch of new data types, functions, and index classes. You can install PostGIS and notice no difference for other data.